# Daemonizing a process in C in Windows

Tags: c, windows

I want to create a process that runs in background( a daemon process ) in C in windows. I know how to make it in Linux, but in windows , the same code is not working. What changes do I need to make.

The code I used in Linux is :

```
    if(fork())
    {
exit(0);
    }
umask(0);
setsid();
close(0);
close(1);
close(2);
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want the process to be able to run when no user is logged on?

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a service(handler) to achieve this in Windows...

search StartServiceCtrlDispatcherA

Comment: -1 you should be compliant with Windows and use the [unicode version of that function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686324(v=vs.85).aspx)